# Puppeteer Get data attribute contains selector

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Markup on localhost

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <button data-action-trigger="btn1">Button text</button>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I need to click on `btn1` by selecting it with its `data-attribute` value `btn`
I get an empty object in the `console.log`

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.setViewport({width: 1440, height: 1200})
  await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/index.html')

  const data = await page.content();

  const btnAction = await page.evaluate(
      () => document.querySelector('[data-action-trigger*="btn1"]'))

  console.log(btnAction) //{}

  await browser.close();
})();
```

I am able to select the element Chrome devTools as

```
document.querySelector(`[data-action-trigger*="btn1"]`)
<button data-action-trigger="btn1">Button text</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatehandlepagefunction-args):

> The only difference between page.evaluate and page.evaluateHandle is
>   that page.evaluateHandle returns in-page object (JSHandle).

Since it's returning an in-page object, you need to use `evaluateHandle` instead of `evaluate`.

```js
await page.waitForSelector('[data-action-trigger*="btn1"]');
const btnAction = await page.evaluateHandle(() => document.querySelector('[data-action-trigger*="btn1"]'))
```

Alternatively, you can use `page.$`:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('[data-action-trigger*="btn1"]');
const btnAction = await page.$('[data-action-trigger*="btn1"]');
```